# Azure recovery service vault: Disk exclusion is not supported for encrypted virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault, azure-disk

I had backedup a VM now the VM has encrypted hard disk. And I get this error.

```
Disk exclusion is not supported for encrypted virtual machines. For more information, refer https://aka.ms/ExcludeDiskFeature
```

There seems to be no way to edit the backup policy. Is the only possible way to delete all backup and start a backup for the same VM again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to backup the vm with an exclusion feature on the disk and as the feature is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/selective-disk-backup-restore#limitations) for an encrypted disk you are not able to back up.

You can remove the exclusion feature for that disk and then backup.

**Command**:

```
az backup protection update-for-vm --vault-name {vaultname} --resource-group {resourcegroup} -c {vmname} -i {vmname} --backup-management-type AzureIaasVM --disk-list-setting resetexclusionsettings
```