# Azure VM backup failing due to Disk Encryption

Tags: azure, disk

I have deployed 10 Azure VMS. All are in running state. I enabled a Backup Policy for all 10 VMs where the Azure will take backup for each VM at 11PM IST. Recently I enabled Disk Encryption for all VMs using the following cloudshell commands .

$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName DevDiskEncryptionKV -ResourceGroupName abcdef
Set-AzVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName abcdef -VMName DEV-VM-005 -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl $KeyVault.VaultUri -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $keyVault.ResourceId.

All disks in VMs are encrypted. But Backup was failed for first 5 VMs (1 to 5) and Next 5 VMs (6 to 10) are fine. Why backup for first 5 VMs are failed. Getting an error code like this:
Error message: Disk exclusion is not supported for encrypted virtual machines.

Can anyone help with the above question?

Comment: any more info? are all the ten VMs the same SKU? same guest OS? Did you check the  
[Support matrix for Azure VM backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-support-matrix-iaas) ? Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: please, take a look at the [unsupported scenarios!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-windows#unsupported-scenarios)

Comment: It would be interesting getting the result of the following command:
`az vm encryption show --name MyVM -g MyResourceGroup`
from a failed backup VM

Comment: All VMs are configured with same configuration. The disk types, size, series etc related things are same for all 10 VMs. But was getting error for only first five VMs. How is it possible? It is question that I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message and the result of the 'az' command I shared before?

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446027/azure-recovery-service-vault-disk-exclusion-is-not-supported-for-encrypted-virt)

Comment: It is having sensitive data..

Comment: I suggested the solution in the "answer" section

Comment: After trying the below mentioned command, I got an error "unrecognized arguments: --backup-management-type AzureIaasVM"

Comment: as per [az backup item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/item?view=azure-cli-latest), **--backup-management-type** is an optional parameter! Can you please try using "AzureStorage" instead of "AzureIaasVM" or simply omitting it?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446027/azure-recovery-service-vault-disk-exclusion-is-not-supported-for-encrypted-virt), can you please run the following:

```
az backup protection update-for-vm --vault-name {vaultname} --resource-group {resourcegroup} -c {vmname} -i {vmname} --backup-management-type AzureIaasVM --disk-list-setting resetexclusionsettings
```

where **vmname** is one of the VM with a failing backup?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start

```
Review below limitations and supported configurations:
```

You can back up and restore ADE encrypted VMs within the same subscription.
Azure Backup supports VMs encrypted using standalone keys. Any key that's a part of a certificate used to encrypt a VM is not currently supported.

Azure Backup supports Cross Region Restore of encrypted Azure VMs to the Azure paired regions.